# C++ Overloading operator+ in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{

    template<typename U>
    friend
    Matrix<U> operator+(const Matrix<U>& a, const Matrix<U>& b);


protected:

    size_t _m, _n;
    T *_alloc;
};

template<typename U>
Matrix<U> operator+(const Matrix<U>& a, const Matrix<U>& b)
{
    if(a._m == b._m && a._n == b._n)
    {
        Matrix<U> ret(a._m, a._n);

        // ...

        return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Matrix dimension mismatch error";
    }
}
```

I've overloaded `operator+` before without problem using non-template classes. Here I'm using a template class.

`Matrix<U> Matrix<U>::operator+(const Matrix<U>&, const Matrix<U>&)` must take either zero or one argument.

It appears that the compiler is ignoring the `friend` keyword.

I also tried

```
friend
template<typename U>
Matrix<U> operator+(const Matrix<U>& a, const Matrix<U>& b);
```

But this gives me a different compiler error.

`expected unqualified-id before 'template'`

How can I overload `operator+` with template classes?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663785/c-operator-overload

Answer (score 4):

You can overload the + operator using a member function or a non-member function.

When the operator is overloaded using a member function, the LHS of the operator is the object on which the function will be called and RHS of the operator is the argument to the function. Hence, the only argument to the member function will be the RHS.

When the operator is overloaded using a non-member function, the LHS of the operator is the first argument of the to the function and RHS of the operator is the second argument to the function.

**Member function**

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
  Matrix operator+(const Matrix& rhs) const {
    ...
  }
};
```

If you want to implement it outside the class definition, you can use:

```
template<typename T>
  Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix& rhs) const {
    ...
  }
```

**Non-member function**

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
  Matrix operator+(const Matrix& lhs, const Matrix& rhs) {
    ...
  }
};
```

If you want to implement it outside the class definition, you need to add some forward declaration code:

```
// Forward declare the class template
template <typename T> class Matrix;

// Declare the function
template <typename T> Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& lhs, const Matrix<T>& rhs);

// Declare the friend in the class definition
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
   friend Matrix operator+<T>(const Matrix& lhs, const Matrix& rhs);
   //                     ^^^^ 
   // This makes operator+<int> a friend of Matrix<int>, not a friend
   // of Matrix<double>
};
```

and then implement the function

```
template <typename T> Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& lhs, const Matrix<T>& rhs)
{
    ...
}
```

With this setup, `oprator+<int>` is a friend of `Matrix<int>` only, not a `friend` of `Matrix<double>`.

If you use

```
template <typename U>
friend
Matrix<U> operator+(const Matrix<U>& a, const Matrix<U>& b);
```

then, all instantiations of `operator+` are friends of all instantiations of `Matrix`, which you don't need.

**Update**

Sample working code:

```
#include <iostream>
 
// Forward declare the class template
template<typename T> class Matrix;

// Declare the function
template <typename T> Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& lhs, const Matrix<T>& rhs);

// Declare the friend in the class definition
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
   friend Matrix operator+<T>(const Matrix& lhs, const Matrix& rhs);
   //                     ^^^^ 
   // This makes operator+<int> a friend of Matrix<int>, not a friend
   // of Matrix<double>
};

template <typename T> Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& lhs, const Matrix<T>& rhs)
{
   return Matrix<T>{};
}

int main()
{
   Matrix<int> a;
   Matrix<int> b;
   Matrix<int> c = a + b;
}
```

Comment: My forward declaration `template<typename T> Matrix<T>` gives the error `error: Matrix does not name a type`

Comment: Sorry, that should be just `Matrix`.

Comment: Still get the same error. `Matrix` does not name a type

Comment: Compiler is gcc 5.2.1, compiling with `--std=c++11`

Comment: @user3728501, I had couple of errors in the code. It fixed now. The update contains working code.

Comment: I had to explicitly instantiate the overload template to make this work since I did not implement the overload operators in the same translation unit. Using the example in this answer this meant I had explicitly write the following: `template class Matrix<int>;` and `template Matrix<int> operator+<int>(const Matrix<int>& lhs, const Matrix<int>& rhs);`

Answer (score 2):

First, let me advise overloading `+=` instead, then write `+` in terms of `+=`.  Second, the friend shouldn't be a template typically.

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
  friend Matrix operator+(Matrix a, const Matrix& b) {
    a += b;
    return std::move(a);
  }
  friend Matrix& operator+=(Matrix& a, const Matrix& b) {
    a.increase_by(b);
    return a;
  }
protected:
  void increase_by( const Matrix& other );

  size_t _m = 0
  size_t _n = 0;
  std::vector<T> _alloc;
};

template<class T>
void Matrix<T>::increase_by(const Matrix<T>& other) {
  if(this->_m == other._m && this->_n == other._n) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < _m*_n; ++i) {
      _alloc[i] += other._alloc[i];
    }
    // ...
  } else {
    throw "Matrix dimension mismatch error";
  }
}
```

Note that the above, with efficient move, will give you reasonably efficient `a+b+c+d+e`, as the lhs is created once and repeatedly moved.

Comment: `return std::move(a);` Why the move? The returned value is an rvalue anyways.

Comment: @BaummitAugen RVO cannot occur, the explicit `move` reminds me.

Comment: Why is that? Why can't `auto c = a + b;` for matrices `a` and `b` not trigger RVO without the `move`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen You cannot RVO from a function argument.  `a` is a function argument of `operator+`.  So I cannot RVO from `a` into `operator+`'s return value.  I take the function argument `a` by-value to allow outsiders to elide into the object I return, which makes `Matrix<int> x = a+b+c+d+e;` very efficient.  I consider the lack of full RVO acceptable, as moving a heap-allocated matrix type is pretty cheap.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. For those who don't know either, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444485/why-is-rvo-disallowed-when-returning-a-parameter) is why.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Don't explicitly declare templates, they are automatically generated. Perhaps someone can explain why in more detail?

```
friend
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b)
{
    if(a._m == b._m && a._n == b._n)
    {
        Matrix ret(a._m, a._n);

        return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Matrix dimension mismatch error";
    }
}
```