# Overloading operators in C++ with template classes

Tags: c++, class, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I have the following template class:

```
    template <class T>
class Matrix {

    public:
        Matrix(size_t rows, size_t columns, const T elements = 0);



        // scalar multiplication
        Matrix<T> operator*(const T& rhs){

            Matrix<T> result(rows, columns);

            for(size_t index = 0; index < rows * columns; ++index){
                result.elements[index] = elements[index] * rhs;
            }

            return result;
        }

        Matrix <T> operator*(const T& lhs, const Matrix<T>& rhs);



        const size_t rows;
        const size_t columns;


        private:

            std::vector<T> elements;
};
```

and the following implementation of the operator* :

```
// scalar multiplication
template <class T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(const T& lhs, const Matrix<T>& rhs){

    Matrix<T> result(rhs.rows, rhs.columns);

    for(size_t index = 0; index < rhs.rows * rhs.columns; ++index){
        result.elements[index] = elements[index] * lhs;
    }
    return result;
}
```

when I try to compile clang says: `error: overloaded 'operator*' must be a unary or binary operator (has 3 parameters)|`

And I don't quite understand, what I am missing in this. In general template classes give me a hard time when it comes to overloading operators and I don't know why. There have been some posts on here on SO on this topic and I tried a few variations of the code but none of them worked.

Comment: as a member function it has `this` implicitly as first parameter but you want to add 2 more. Lets say you have `Matrix a,b,c;` your operator would be called like `a.operator*(b,c)` does this make sense? no ;)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853204/c-overloading-operator-in-a-template-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple and reasonably efficient way to solve this problem is as follows:

1. Implement `Matrix& operator *=(SomeType const&)` and similar operations first.  These are *mutating* operations that change an instance of the class, then return a reference to `*this`.
2. Implement other operations as inline friends in terms of `*=`, where the lhs (usually) argument is taken by-value, modified and returned.

This tends to be really simple and quite often more efficient than starting with `operator*` instead of `operator*=`.

So you'll have:

```
 template<class T, etc>
 struct Matrix{
   Matrix& operator*=(T const&);
   Matrix& operator*=(Matrix const&);
   Matrix& operator+=(Matrix const&);
```

which you implement traditionally.  Then:

```
   friend Matrix operator*(T const& t, Matrix m){ m*=t; return m; }
   friend Matrix operator*(Matrix m, T const& t){ m*=t; return m; }

   friend Matrix operator*(Matrix lhs, Matrix const& rhs){ lhs*=rhs; return lhs; }
   friend Matrix operator+(Matrix lhs, Matrix const& rhs){ lhs+=rhs; return lhs; }
```

and now you only need to implement a few, traditional, methods.

These `friend` operators are non-template inline non-method functions that are auto-generated for each template instance of Matrix.

Your immediate problem was your non-static operator actually took an implicit `this` in addition to its two explicit parameters, and binary operators cannot take 3 arguments.

---

The complex and even more efficient solution involves a technique often called "expression templates".  The disadvantage is that expression templates are more complex to write, and have a few points of fragility around the `auto` keyword and similar situations.

As an example:

```
Matrix m = m1 * m2 + m3 * m4 + m5 + m6;
```

An expression template will do the above with only one allocation of the internal data of a matrix.

My above code will copy `m1`, multiply the result by `m2`.  Then it will copy `m3`, then multiply that by `m4`.  Then it will add up everything without making any additional copies.  Finally, this result will be moved into `m`.

So two matrices will be created instead of 1 in the expression template case.

A more-naive solution (like the OP's design) would create 5 Matrices instead of 2.

Comment: thank you! Very often I'm not sure if I should implement a function within the class definition or outside of it. Is there a general rule?

Comment: @kimsay If it is short and you are ok with `inline` and its perils, do it in the class definition.  If it isn't, put it elsewhere?  In the case of the above Koenig friend operators, you *must* do it in the class definition (as there is no way to refer to the operator outside of the class): this also means (to me) that they should always be short.

Comment: also the friend is only there to access private fields?

Comment: @kimsay nope: it does a bunch of things.  It makes ADL work smoothly, makes the operators themselves non-template (which has some nice properties: template operators can be fragile), it makes them non-member binary operators, etc.

Comment: sorry, got it! Thank you! @ Yakk

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `Matrix <T> operator*(const T& lhs, const Matrix<T>& rhs);` as member function, which has an implicit parameter `this`, that why compiler complains it "has 3 parameters".

You can make it a free template function,

```
template <class T>
class Matrix {
    ...
    template <class Z>
    friend Matrix<Z> operator*(const Z& lhs, const Matrix<Z>& rhs);
    ...
};
```

and

```
// scalar multiplication
template <class Z>
Matrix<Z> operator*(const Z& lhs, const Matrix<Z>& rhs){

    Matrix<Z> result(rhs.rows, rhs.columns);

    for(size_t index = 0; index < rhs.rows * rhs.columns; ++index){
        result.elements[index] = elements[index] * lhs;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried friend earlier, but it doesn't work either, @songyuanyao

Comment: @kimsay My bad. Fixed.

Comment: thanks @songyuanyao . Do I only need friend for accessing private fields, or is there more to it?

Comment: @kimsay Only for accessing private fields, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is a member function. Member functions have a hidden parameter, the this pointer.

You either need to make your operator* a non-member function or you need to get rid of one of the arguments to your operator* function (which will then multiply the data in "this" with the data in the incoming Matrix`<T>`.)