# Declare non-template friend function for template class outside the class

Tags: c++, templates, friend-function

The following non-template code [works well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdd26d29049c53ee):

```
struct A { };

struct B
{
    B() {}
    B(const A&) {}
    friend B operator+(const B&) { return B(); }    
};

B operator+(const B&);

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    +b;
    +a;
}
```

But if I make classes in this code templated:

```
template <class T>
struct A { };

template <class T>
struct B
{
    B() {}
    B(const A<T>&) {}
    friend B operator+(const B&) { return B(); }    
};

template <class T>
B<T> operator+(const B<T>&); // not really what I want 

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    B<int> b;
    +b;
    +a;
}
```

some kind of [troubles appear](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa5e017a4eedb94a):

> error: no match for 'operator+' (operand type is 'A<int>')

**Is it possible to declare non-template friend function for template class outside the class** (as I did for non-template classes above)**?**

I can solve the problem by adding [template operator](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8103e7c3fecc4621) for `A<T>` argument and call friend function inside, but it is not interesting.

**UPD:**

Another workaround (inspired by [R Sahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022197/3240681)) is add `friend` declaration for class `A`:

```
template <class T>
struct A { 
    friend B<T> operator+(const B<T>&);
};
```

but this [gives a warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25b9a295a2870eb9), and I don't know how to fix it correctly.

Comment: I am not sure what you desire to have. B is a template here, so you need a template parameter to operate on it. What should the template parameter be if it is not dynamically determined?

Comment: @IceFire what kind of `dynamically` do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to declare non-template friend function for template class outside the class (as I did for non-template classes above)?

Yes, it is possible. However, what you probably need is a function template too, and make sure that `operator+<int>` is a `friend` of `A<int>`, `operator+<double>` is a `friend` of `A<double>`, etc.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35854179/434551 to understand how that can be done.

Comment: Adding a `friend` declaration for class `A` works. But a [warning appears](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25b9a295a2870eb9).

Comment: @alexolut, The warning message makes sense. The function `B<T> operator+(const B<T>&);` has not been declared to be function template before it is made a `friend` of `A<T>`. Take a look at a simplified version that does not use `A`: http://ideone.com/U5EJPp. And another version that has `A` but does `A` is not doing much: http://ideone.com/WjpxyY.

Comment: A second version does not use `a` object. If I add it - I got [same error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41021d01e4013662) as in original question. N.B. ideone does not show any warnings if no errors occured.

Comment: @alexolut, I took out the line that had `+a` since it is an undefined function. `B<T> operator+(const B<T>&);` only supports the unary `+` operator on `B<T>`, not on `A<T>`.

Comment: but there is implicit conversion from A to B by B's ctor, and my desire is to make it works (like in example of non-template version of A & B)

Comment: @alexolut, implicit conversion is not performed when deducing typenames of function templates. That's why `+b` works but `+a` does not.

Comment: But it works when I declare friend inside A. Is not it?

Comment: @alexolut, no it does not.

Comment: Are you sure? Implicit conversion [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58fb6a77b4be1b00).

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to declare non-template friend function for template class outside the class?**

Answer: yes, but... you need to declare a function for each one combinations you use:

This funcion solves the problem for your puntual declaration:

```
A<int> operator+(const A<int>&) { return A<int>(); }
```

But, if you use A< double>, you need to explicity declare other function:

```
A<double> operator+(const A<double>&) { return A<double>(); }
```

Is not requiered friend because in a struct all member are public

Comment: My question is about **declaration** only, not definition. The only one definition of `operator+` positioned inside class's `B` definition, and I don't want to add any other overloading functions. `friend` is necessary here for implicit argument conversion, not for accessing private members. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890051/implicit-conversion-when-overloading-operators-for-template-classes) & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381164/friend-and-inline-method-whats-the-point).