# Declare non-template function in a template class?

Tags: c++, friend-function

> **NOTE**: this post is **different from this one**: [Declare non-template friend function for template class outside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021863/declare-non-template-friend-function-for-template-class-outside-the-class), so please read my question before marking it as duplicate.

I want to declare a non-template friend function inside a class template, and the arguments and return type of that friend function is **unrelated** to the template argument. How should I do that?

Please note it is different from that previous question because in *that question*, arguments and return type of that friend function is *related* to the template argument.

Example, adapted from that question above:

```
// class.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    T value;
    int value2;
    B() : value2(1) {}
    friend void modify(const int&); // unrelated to T!
    void printValue2() {
        modify(value2);
        cout << value2 << endl;
    }   
};

// define friend function foo() in a class.cpp file, not in the header
void modify(const int &v) { v = v * 2 + 1; } // HOW should I write it?

// main.cpp
int main() {
   B<int> b;
   b.printValue2();
   return 0;
}
```

I know I can declare `modify()` outside this template class so it becomes a vanilla, ordinary function. But I want only this template class to have access to `modify()`. Alternatively, to achieve this goal of access control, I could define `modify()` to be a static method in this template class, but that would make the method a template method, forcing me to define it in the header.

**Followup**: if the friend approach above doesn't work, how should I achieve the two goals at the same time:

- access control: only that class template can access `modify()`
- be able to define `modify()` in a *.cpp file, rather in a header.

**Accepted Answer**:

To achieve the two goals above, don't abuse friendship.

The best practice is let the class template privately inherit a **non-template base class**, and  in that base class declare common **non-template methods** that are unrelated to template arguments.

Therefore, you are able to define these methods in a separate *.cpp file, reducing the header's size.

Comment: If `modify` is going to be modifying a `B<T>` then it is going to have to be a template.  Since you need to make it a template and put it in a header file you might as well make it a static or non static member function.

Comment: @NathanOliver from `modify()`'s point of view, it doesn't care if it is able to modify a `B<T>` object - it just modifies whatever integer that is passed in reference. Does this give me some leeway?

Comment: @Walter yes, but I want only `B<T>` to have access to `modify()`. If I define `modify()` to be a method, it will become templated. I don't want it to be templated.

Comment: @Walter I disagree. Yes, friendship controls access - it should be used that way in normal cases. However, if I don't use friendship, `modify()` would either have to be declared outside the class template (causing it to be callable by others) or have to be a member method (causing it to be templated).

Comment: @Leedehai Okay, I now think I understand your question (it could have been phrased clearer ...). I have withdrawn the close vote and my comments.

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std;` especially in header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use private inheritance instead of friendship:

```
// class.h
#include <iostream>

class B_helper
{
protected:
    static void modify(int &v);
};

template <typename T>
struct B : private B_helper
{
    T value;
    int value2;
    B() : value2(1) {}

    void printValue2() {
        modify(value2);
        std::cout << value2 << std::endl;
    }   
};

// class.cpp
void B_helper::modify(int &v) { v = v * 2 + 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
// class.cpp
void modify(const int &v) { v = v * 2 + 1; }
```

You are effectively abusing friendship, but ok. What this means is that you need to work around what it means to declare a function with `friend`: It is only visible through ADL! Now there is *no* way to refer to `modify`, because `modify` doesn't depend on `B`, so `B`'s scope is never searched for a function named `modify`.

There is a work-around, but it's not pretty. You need to declare `modify` in every function where you use it. You could also declare it in global scope, but then everyone can call it. Alternatively, you can always declare it in a `detail` namespace (but this has the same issue a bit):

```
template<typename T>
void B<T>::printValue2() {
    void modify(const int&);
    modify(value2);
    cout << value2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: But I want some methods template class to be able to call `modify()`. Making it static in the cpp file would defeat that purpose, because template class's methods are defined in the header. no?

Comment: @Leedehai Wait, why do you want to define `modify` in a .cpp file then? Like if your whole class's definition is in the header, one more function doesn't hurt. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, `friend`ship controls access to a class. As long as your function `modify()` is a standalone function, it cannot be befriended. As you want to call it from a template, it cannot be hidden it in a .cpp file either, but must be visible with the definition of the class template B and its member using `modify()`.

One solution is to put `modify` as a `static` method in a auxiliary non-template class, which in turn befriends the template `B<>`.

```
// file foo.h (header)

namespace foo {
    template<typename> class B;            // forward declaration

    class exclusive_for_B
    {
        template<typename T>
        friend class B<T>;

        static void modify(int&x)          // must take int&, not const int&
        { x &= x+42; }
    };

    template<typename T>
    class B
    {
        int val;
     public:
        ...
        void printvalue()
        {
            exclusive_for_B::modify(val);  // access via friendship
            std::cout << val << '\n';
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @KorelK ?? I don't understand your comment, I'm afraid.

Comment: @KorelK yes, it would make a difference: it would be accessible to everybody, which the OP explicitly wanted to avoid.