# Overload operator [] with a template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload `operator[]` using a template so it is possible to *choose* what type is returned. Simplified example:

```
class A
{
    uint8_t buff[10];

public:
    template<typename T> 
    T operator[] (uint var)
    {
        return (T)buff[var]; 
    }
};
```

Now I want to be able to do something like this:

```
abc<uint16_t>[5]; // Clearly not allowed

abc.operator[]<uint16_t>(5); // This works but it's stupid
```

**Question:** Is it possible to overload operator [] this way? If not, what is the correct way to achieve it?

Comment: You wont be able to use it this way : `abc<uint16_t>[5]`. Give a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853204/c-overloading-operator-in-a-template-class

Comment: As the duplicate indicates, you need to write out `operator[]` unless you can implicitly deduce the template argument. You can't in this case. Maybe an `at<uint_16_t>(5);` or something would suit your needs better.

Comment: @AdrienGivry The link was not present at the time of my comment. But the first portion of the comment is still redundant.

Comment: Such implicit casting is often a bad idea. And C-style casting is really a red flag of you doing something wrong. Return the actual type and have the caller do the conversion if needed.

Comment: But if you use the template parameter just for the cast, why not use the cast outside the function, eliminating the need of templates?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is just a very simplified example created to show the idea of syntax I'd like to achieve

Comment: Depending on use-case, requirements and design, it might be a better idea to have an explicit "convert to this type" function, as in `template<typename T> T as(unsigned index) { return reinterpret_cast<T>(buff[index]); }` Another way which is usually nicer is to have the `operator[]` function return a *proxy object* with such an `as` function. Then you could do e.g. `abc[5].as<uint16_t>()`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for here

Comment: Or you can write a small macro : `#define ELEMENT(Value) operator[]<decltype(Value)>(Value)` and use it like `auto result = foo.ELEMENT(5u);`. This way, you'll be able to call any templated `operator[]` without writing too much

Comment: @AdrienGivry Each time a macro like this is being written, a kitten dies.